# What causes Google Auto ML to error out with "Missing labels in training/test/eval split"?

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-automl

I have a training set of 1.6 M records and my target has 493 unique values (categorical data).

I am getting an error saying

```
Missing label(s) in train split: target column contains 493 distinct values, but only 485 present.
Missing label(s) in test split: target column contains 493 distinct values, but only 403 present. 
Missing label(s) in eval split: target column contains 493 distinct values, but only 403 present. 
There must be at least one instance of each label value in every split.
```

What do they mean then saying `present` are there empty values in my data set or what kind of errors do I look in my training data set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root cause of this issue is that you do not have enough data of one, or several, of the distinct labels. That causes one of the values to not appear on one of the sets. By default AutoML would split the data into Train, Eval and Test as 80%, 10%, 10%. This may depend on which section of AutoML are you using but I think that it is roughly the same for all (see [AutoML Tables](https://cloud.google.com/automl-tables/docs/prepare#split) or [AutoML Vision](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/prepare#training_vs_evaluation_datasets)).

It is required that all the labels exist in all the three splits. Therefore, even if all the labels are there in the original data, it does not mean that the label will be in all the splits. Given the amount of data you have, this may happen if some labels are uncommon (low ratio).

Solution for this are:

- Add more data that contains the troublesome labels. Try to balance the amount of data you have of each label to ensure all of them will appear in each split.
- Use the [data split column](https://cloud.google.com/automl-tables/docs/prepare#ml-use), the [time column](https://cloud.google.com/automl-tables/docs/prepare#time) or any other of the other known methods to manually specify each of the splits.
- Remove the labels that have too small occurrences. This can be a quick solution if you are unable to follow any of the aforementioned ones

Alternatively, this can be due to some data not properly recognized by AutoML which results in invalid data and those records being discarded which ultimately results in the aforementioned root cause. If that is the case, which can be checked by trying the aforementioned solutions and failing to solve the problem, I recommend reaching [GCP support](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs) as it is probably an issue in the AutoML feature.

Comment: I am using tables and the target is a four digit int.

Comment: In the data sets there a few labels that only a couple of records.
Is 3 records per label is minimally sufficient? (at this stage I am not very concerned with accuracy)

Comment: 3 records per label could be minimally sufficient if you follow the second advice and manually specify the splits. In any case, it would result in a terrible accuracy. At least 100 records per label are recommended. If they are randomly made you will need quite a few more records (than 3) to ensure they appear in all the splits. I would suggest around the aforementioned 100 records. Bear in mind that given your total amount of records, 1.6 million, your labels need to have a minimum presence in the dataset to be minimally relevant. Let say 1/10000, which still yields 160 records per label.